# Is this function semantically correct?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to initiate a class depending on two conditions, if the class hasn't been initiated and if a class to which all the methods are applied is present in the markup :

```
if (!window.Recipes && !$('#page').find('#recipesSearchResults').length) {
    return window.Recipes = new Recipes;
} else {
    return true;
}
```

Is the above statement correct ? Or am I missing something ?

Comment: your syntax is correct but logically it could be either correct or wrong... it depends :)

Comment: (Semantically, classes are instantiated, not initiated, since they require instances.)

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan ~ in what cases could it be correct or wrong ? if I follow Curt's answer could I be having issues when doing the if statement or the instantiating of the class ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`!$('#page').find('#recipesSearchResults').length` will return `true` if the length of `$('#page').find('#recipesSearchResults')` **is not** `0`.

However, `#recipesSearchResults` is an ID selector, and not a class selector.

> ...and if a class to which all the methods are applied is present in
>   the markup

You should change this to `.recipesSearchResults`:

```
!$('#page').find('.recipesSearchResults').length
```